# Read Content in Dll programatically and write it into another file in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

As part of my project I need to download a Zipped folder from a remote server and then Unzip it . For unzipping I am using SharpZipLib. My doubt is if I use BinaryReader and BinaryWriter to read and write will my new dll work properly or weather the new dll will get corrupted.

Comment: Did I get your question properly? If you can download the zip file properly and unzip it flawlessly, then why you need to read and write that dll again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That classes seems fine to me.

"Currupted" means "some code piece have a bug and I didn't spotted it". So, yes, you can have corruption problems if:

- Your packing code have a bug
- Your transmission code have a bug
- Your unpacking code have a bug

Generally speaking, it's up to you get a corrupted file, or not.

By the way, `System.Reflection.Assembly.Load` methods in Silverlight:

> (...) has a SecurityCriticalAttribute attribute, which restricts it to internal use by the .NET Framework for Silverlight class library. Application code that uses this member throws a MethodAccessException.

So, I hope you have a good plan to deal with that.